# How to setup logging using aiohttp web server

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

I have a webserver and i want to be able to log the request, the response and time taken.

I came across this https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/logging.html but when i try to use the drop in replacement logging AccessLogger class. It fails with the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/kay/.local/share/virtualenvs/entity-extractor-BuK_iA9e/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_log.py", line 233, in log
> self.logger.info(self._log_format % tuple(values), extra=extra)
> AttributeError: type object 'AccessLogger' has no attribute 'info'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/kay/.local/share/virtualenvs/entity-extractor-BuK_iA9e/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 472, in start
> self.log_access(request, resp, loop.time() - now)
> File "/home/kay/.local/share/virtualenvs/entity-extractor-BuK_iA9e/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 348, in log_access
> self.access_logger.log(request, response, time)
> File "/home/kay/.local/share/virtualenvs/entity-extractor-BuK_iA9e/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_log.py", line 235, in log
> self.logger.exception("Error in logging")
> AttributeError: type object 'AccessLogger' has no attribute 'exception'
> ERROR:aiohttp.server:Unhandled exception
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/kay/.local/share/virtualenvs/entity-extractor-BuK_iA9e/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_log.py", line 233, in log
> self.logger.info(self._log_format % tuple(values), extra=extra)
> AttributeError: type object 'AccessLogger' has no attribute 'info'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/kay/.local/share/virtualenvs/entity-extractor-BuK_iA9e/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 472, in start
> self.log_access(request, resp, loop.time() - now)
> File "/home/kay/.local/share/virtualenvs/entity-extractor-BuK_iA9e/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 348, in log_access
> self.access_logger.log(request, response, time)
> File "/home/kay/.local/share/virtualenvs/entity-extractor-BuK_iA9e/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_log.py", line 235, in log
> self.logger.exception("Error in logging")

**logger.py**

```
from aiohttp.abc import AbstractAccessLogger
class AccessLogger(AbstractAccessLogger):

    def log(self, request, response, time):
        self.logger.info(f'{request.remote} '
                         f'"{request.method} {request.path} '
                         f'done in {time}s: {response.status}')
```

**server.py**

```
from aiohttp import web
from src.api import API
from src.logger import AccessLogger

server = API()
web.run_app(server.app,access_log=AccessLogger)
```

My end goal is to also have logs in a dictionary json format. If there is someway i can achieve this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong attribute. You must pass your custom logger as `access_log_class`. (https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.run_app)

```
from aiohttp import web
from src.api import API
from src.logger import AccessLogger

server = API()
web.run_app(server.app, access_log_class=AccessLogger)
```

`access_log` must be a `logging.Logger` instance

Comment: thanks, any idea why logging doesent work when using gunicorn?

Comment: @Kay MB because you need custom logging conf, check python docs to create it (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig). Also, you must provide logger to gunicorn

Comment: I setup gunicorn and used that for logging, but do you know how i can get json logs?

Comment: @Kay it's not an easy task, AFAIK you need to implement custom logging formatted (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects)

Comment: ye i stopped using gunicorn for logs and instead i create json logs using a middleware in aiohttp.